# PyModbus RTU -> RTU Forwarder

Tags: python, pymodbus

Relatively new to modbus and have been trying to implement a parity converter, that is a program that takes in Packets with say Even parity and sends out the same exact packets with Odd parity. End goal is to have the program spliced between an end device (address: 2) and the master to convert parities.

To do this I tried setting up the PyModbus Forwarder example with the server configured for Even Parity, and the client configured for Odd parity. The Server receives all the traffic from my Master device, but there seems to be some issue on the client side. From the log, the program selects the proper COM ports but then client.connect() prints "Connecting to None", which is where I am stuck. I also am not receiving any packets on the end device. How can I get the client to passthrough the masters messages?

```
import asyncio
import logging
import sys
from pymodbus.examples.helper import get_commandline
from pymodbus.client import AsyncModbusSerialClient
from pymodbus.datastore import ModbusServerContext
from pymodbus.datastore.remote import RemoteSlaveContext
from pymodbus.server import StartAsyncSerialServer

_logger = logging.getLogger()
_logger.setLevel("DEBUG")
_logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout))

async def run_forwarder(client_port, port):
    """Run forwarder setup."""
    txt = f"### start forwarder, listen {port}, connect to {client_port}"
    _logger.info(txt)

    client = AsyncModbusSerialClient(
        port=client_port,
        baudrate=19200,
        parity="O"
    )
    await client.connect()
    assert client.connected
    print("done")
    # If required to communicate with a specified client use slave=<slave_id>
    # in RemoteSlaveContext
    # For e.g to forward the requests to slave with slave address 1 use
    # store = RemoteSlaveContext(client, slave=1)
    slave_address = 2
    store = RemoteSlaveContext(client, slave=slave_address)
    context = ModbusServerContext(slaves=store, single=True)
    print("done 2")
    await StartAsyncSerialServer(context=context, port=port, baudrate=19200, parity="E")
    # loop forever


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(run_forwarder(client_port="COM6", port="COM5"))
```

[image]